# How To Change RichTextBox selected Text Color? C#

Tags: c#

How to change richtextbox selected Text Color?

when select text by mouse and change color by click on context menu item!

```
private void ContextMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ColorDialog c = new ColorDialog();
            if (c.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (text.SelectedText != null)
                {
                    // how coding for here?
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.SelectedText))
{
 text.SelectionColor = c.Color;
}
```